# Instagram iPhone hook url scheme changed

Tags: ios, instagram

It seems that the update of Instagram Client on Oct.28th made a slight change to the hook url scheme on iOS development.

I found it that the previous "**instagram://camera**" url scheme act unexpected link us to the camera page in Instagram App, not the photo library before.

I also found that the **Boomerang** App that Instagram owned itself hook the photo library correctly, but I didn't find the relative hook on the api page.So I think there might exist a **private hook** scheme.

Is there any way I can hook through Instagram App to photo library directly like before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use "instagram://library?AssetPath=%@" to access the photo library, this url scheme not documented.

Comment: is this still working for you? It opens the default view of instagram for me

Comment: @martynmlostekk yeah, it still work to open photo library, but it seems that the default chosen photo is not the one we want to display in it.

Comment: yep. for me too, it simply opens the photo library with nothing selected. can you post one full urll you are passing to the ```openUrl``` call?

Comment: I experience the same behavior. It used to open with the asset-path already selected. Now they seem to have changed something, and it doesn't select any asset. Boomerang still works and they are doing the right thing, of course, they own both apps. We need to figure out what has changed.

Answer (score 0):

From their documentation

> URL   OPENS
>
> camera    The camera (or photo library on non-camera devices)

Are you using a camera or non camera device? That should answer your question.

Comment: not the device issue.I use that camera url a long time, and it works fine to open the photo library.It occur to open camera only after the Instagram App updated.

Comment: All I can say is that Instagram probably updated their UX flow and made it so it goes to the camera. There doesn't seem to be a hook for photo library.

Comment: yeah, the doc didn't show the photo library relative api, but the Instagram Boomerang App still can access it.So I'm wondering if there exists a private url scheme to access photo lib directly.@noobsmcgoobs

Comment: I don't remember the API or the app that well, but in the past was the photo library attached to the camera or in the same functionality area?

Comment: well, in the past, we access the photo library through instagram://camera url scheme,although the doc says that it access the camera.but actually it did access the photo library.now it changed to access the camera instead.@noobsmcgoobs